# Python, delete attribute from instance but not from source

Tags: python, class, instance

I have the following three classes `measurement`, `submeasurement` and `environment`. `submeasurement` takes an instance of `measurement` and `environment` takes an instance of `submeasurement` as input argument.

I would like to keep the attributes of each class in order. Therefore I wrote the method `set_cls_as_attr`, which is supposed to convert: `self.submeasurement.measurement --> self.measurement` and to delete: `self.submeasurement.measurement`.

```
class environment():
    def __init__(self, submeasurement):
        self.submeasurement = submeasurement
        self.set_cls_as_attr(submeasurement, 'measurement')

    def set_cls_as_attr(self, obj, cls_name):
        setattr(self, cls_name, getattr(obj, cls_name))
        print(obj.__class__.__name__ + '.' + cls_name)
        if hasattr(self, obj.__class__.__name__ ):
            if hasattr(eval('self.' + obj.__class__.__name__), cls_name):
                delattr(eval('self.' + obj.__class__.__name__), cls_name)

class measurement():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.__class__.__name__

class submeasurement():
    def __init__(self, measurement):
        self.name = self.__class__.__name__
        self.measurement = measurement

meas=measurement()
sub_meas=submeasurement(meas)
env= environment(sub_meas)
```

This works fine, but it also deletes `sub_meas.measurement` and this I do not want to happen. Is there a way to do that? I also tried `__dict__.pop('measurement')` but this does the same.

Comment: Try doing an explicit copy of  `sub_meas` in python everything is passed by reference, so your original object will be affected

Comment: I can not do that because every instance is supposed to be able to change values from the other instances attributes. For example if I change `sub_meas.measurement.some_attr` to 3 I would like that `meas.some_attr is 3`
I hope this is not a pythonic no-go.

Comment: Maybe you are complicating it too much then. the pytonic (or OOP) way would be just to keep the member `submeasurement` inside `environment`. instead of "taking instances" of one another. from an outsider point of view, `set_cls_as_attr` is not helping you with anything

Comment: Yes you may be right. The only reason I wanted to do this is code-readability.
Apart from the order of initialization there is no logic why it should be  `env.submeasurement.measurement` and not `env.measurement`. For everything else the connection between `environment` and `measurement` is the same as the one between `submeasurement` and `measurement`.

Comment: agree,  I don't know what your code is meant for, but it woyuld make more sense for `measurement` to have a member `submeasurement` **OR**  `submeasurement should inherit `measurement`